# Where is the man page of various flags showed in `ip link show DEV` command?

Tags: ip

Where is the man page of various flags showed in `ip link show DEV` command?
e.g,

```
31: swp28: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9216 qdisc pfifo_fast master bridge state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 11:22:33a:c7:4e:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

5: ens6f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:96:91:cb:ec:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Could not find the man page of the flags of `mq`, `pfifo_fast`, `master`, `bridge`,
so far the most comprehensive help page is https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-link.8.html, but still not what I want.

Any better man page?

EDIT: furthermore, where is the man page of the result showed by
`ip -d link show DEV` command?
e.g,

```
    link/ether 11:22:33:c7:4e:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65535
    sx_netdev
    bridge_slave state forwarding priority 8 cost 100 hairpin off guard off root_block off fastleave off learning on flood on port_id 0x801c port_no 0x1c designated_port 32796 designated_cost 0 designated_bridge 8000.1c:34:da:c7:4e:0 designated_root 8000.1c:34:da:c7:4e:0 hold_timer    0.00 message_age_timer    0.00 forward_delay_timer    0.00 topology_change_ack 0 config_pending 0 proxy_arp off proxy_arp_wifi off mcast_router 1 mcast_fast_leave off mcast_flood on neigh_suppress off group_fwd_mask 0x0 group_fwd_mask_str 0x0 group_fwd_maskhi 0x0 group_fwd_maskhi_str 0x0 vlan_tunnel off isolated off addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 switchid ffffffffffff
```

I know the meaning of `master bridge` is that the dev is a bridge slave, it is master device name is `bridge`, but there are still a lot of flags, seems I have to google them one-by-one.

Comment: Read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: That is the problem, the man page `man ip ip-link` also have no information of the flags output by ip link show command.

Comment: There are flags in man page but that is listed in ip link add or set command, some flags are not listed there.

Comment: Most of it is in `man ip-link`, remaining part in the `ip` command itself: `ip link add type bridge help`. Once you see a keyword there, you can check it in the man. Eg: Seen `mcast_last_member_count` in the previous command's output? Its explanation is in `man ip-link`.

Comment: @A.B thanks, the `ip link add type bridge help` helps. Could you please post an answer, I will accept it, I think many developer don't know this, they just search round and round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual of the sub-command [`ip link`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-link.8.html) (`man ip link` or `man ip-link`) is distinct from the manual of the command [`ip`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html) (`man ip`) and should include all possible parameters for the `ip link` command.

The `ip link` command itself (unless compiled in embedded environment) includes help about grammar and syntax for its parameters:

```
ip link help
```

In addition, for most interface types, supplying `help` as interface type parameter: after the interface type (preceded by the sub-subcommand `add` or for some types which aren't simply added, by `set` and an existing device of the correct type) will provide the additional grammar/syntax for the interface type. Examples for `veth`, `bridge` and `bridge_slave` types:

```
$ ip link add type veth
Usage: ip link <options> type veth [peer <options>]
To get <options> type 'ip link add help'

$ ip link add type bridge help
Usage: ... bridge [ fdb_flush ]
          [ forward_delay FORWARD_DELAY ]
          [ hello_time HELLO_TIME ]
          [ max_age MAX_AGE ]
          [ ageing_time AGEING_TIME ]
          [ stp_state STP_STATE ]
          [ priority PRIORITY ]
          [ group_fwd_mask MASK ]
          [ group_address ADDRESS ]
          [ vlan_filtering VLAN_FILTERING ]
          [ vlan_protocol VLAN_PROTOCOL ]
[...]

$ ip link set dev swp28 type bridge_slave help
Usage: ... bridge_slave [ fdb_flush ]
            [ state STATE ]
            [ priority PRIO ]
            [ cost COST ]
            [ guard {on | off} ]
            [ hairpin {on | off} ]
[...]
```

A description of almost all of these parameters can be found in the manual in the interface section they belong to. For OP's example about *bridge_slave*, [`ip-link(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-link.8.html) has a [bridge_slave section](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8.en.html#Bridge) where most parameter's descriptions can be found. Example:

> `vlan_tunnel { on | off }` - controls whether vlan to tunnel mapping is
> enabled on the port. By default this flag is off.

But then a few rarely used parameters might not be described here especially when a more specialized command is available. The next parameter seen in OP's example: `isolated` has its syntax but not its description. Its [description](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/bridge.8#isolated) can be found in the [`bridge` command's manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/bridge.8.html) (`bridge` together with `ip link` supersedes and obsoletes `brctl`) when using its [`bridge link`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/bridge.8#bridge_link_set_-_set_bridge_specific_attributes_on_a_port) subcommand, which might overlap with some uses of `ip link ... type bridge_slave ...`:

> `isolated on` or `isolated off`
>
> Controls whether a given port will be isolated, which means it will be able to communicate with non-isolated ports only. By default
> this flag is off.

(This example is similar to [PVLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN).)